# CSS Calc with Variables and Multiplication

Tags: css

I'm validating my CSS using the Nu Html Checker:

https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Consider the following CSS:

```
:root {
  --target-size: 48px;
}

.test1 {
  flex: 0 0 calc(var(--target-size) + 1px);
}

.test2 {
  min-height: calc(var(--target-size) - 0.5rem);
}

.test3 {
  flex: 0 0 calc(320px - 3 * var(--target-size));
}
```

The validator reports no error with `.test1` and `.test2`.

However, for `.test3`, the validator reports this error:

Error: flex: The types are incompatible.

I know that the CSS rules stipulates that for multiplication, at least one of the arguments must be a `<number>`. I don't see that violated. I've tried nesting the multiplication in another calc(), but the error persists.

Any idea what's wrong with that rule and how to correct it?

Comment: Have you tried `flex: 0 0 calc(320px - (var(—target-size) * 3)))`? I think it has to do with the loose ‘3’...

Comment: You said it first, I didn't see this sorry

Comment: No, actually your suggestion pointed in the right direction. It is the operand order that appears to be critical. '3 * var(--target-size)' fails. 'var(--target-size) * 3' passes. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you switch the order of multiplication it seems like it works:

`flex: 0 0 calc(320px - var(--target-size) * 3);`

You're right about the `<number>` argument but missed that the number has to be on the right side of the multiplication.